# TkInter display list of images next to each other in one window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a folder of images which I add to a list and process. At the end of the process, I would like to display the images next to each other in a `TkInter` window, at present with the code I have, only the last image in the folder is displayed. I'm also using only one panel to display these images and I'm passing a list of images to the `panel.image` method but I suppose it's the wrong way to do it, because it does not work

```
images = list()
for item in os.listdir(mypath):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath, item))
    if image is not None:
        if image.shape[0] > image.shape[1]:
            image = imutils.rotate_bound(image, 90)
        images.append(image)

        r = 400.0 / image.shape[1]
        dim = (400, int(image.shape[0] * r))
        resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        ###[Image processing]###

        imageslist = list()
        original = Image.fromarray(resized)
        original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
        imageslist.append(original)

if panelA is None:

     for image in imageslist:
        panelA = Label(image=image)
        panelA.image = image
        panelA.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10)

else:

    for image in imageslist:

        panelA.configure(image=image)
        panelA.image = image

 root = Tk()
 panelA = None
 root.mainloop()
```

#### UPDATE

Now, with the code below, all images are shown (vertically though) however, whenever i reset the loop with the click of a button (in order to process images from another folder) the first image from the first folder remainst there, while the rest of the images are indeed from the new folder, this is very strange and i really can't understand why this happens, I destroyed the panel, i checked the list and it contains the images from the new folder after every loop, but that first images is constantly sitting there for some reason

```
 if panelA is None:
        # the first panel will store our original image
    for image in imageslist:
        panelA = Label(image=image)
        panelA.image = image
        panelA.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10)

    # otherwise, update the image panels
else:
    panelA.destroy()
    for image in imageslist:
        panelA = Label(image=image)
        panelA.image = image
        panelA.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10)
```

Here's how it looks like, first loop:

[image: first loop]

Second loop, images are taken from another folder, first image from first folder is still there at the top, that image is not in the new folder and the list has been cleared at the beginning of the second loop so it's not taken from imageslist:

[image: second loop]

Comment: The `image=` option of a Label only accepts a single image.  You would either need to use multiple Labels, combine the images into one using PIL, or use a different widget such as a Canvas or Text that can have multiple images inserted into them.

Comment: Well, you're putting all of the images at exactly the same position - at most one is going to be visible.  The usual reason for blank images in Tkinter is that you referred to the image only via a local variable, and it got garbage collected as soon as the function exited: is the code you posted actually inside a function?  If so, you need to store `imageslist` either as a global variable, or as an attribute to some object or widget that's going to be around for as long as the images are visible.

Comment: Why not just use `grid`? Or change the pack to `"left"`. You can get the column index by changing the iteration `enumerate(iterable)` and using the index.

Comment: You can write a function to destroy the label and recreate it with the first image in the folder. That could work.

Comment: Why would you use such distributing images? My boss just walked by and saw these pictures, and the look on his face was unpleasant.Use nicer pictures pls.